# Hide scrollbar like the teehan+lax website

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, hide, overflow

I have a navigation which very much ressembles the teehan+lax website and would like to hide the scrollbar when "menu" is clicked, and still be able to scroll.

Like here: teehanlax.com

I tried using overflow:hidden on the container with overflow-y: scroll on the content but it didn't hide the scrollbar.

I also went through the same questions posted to stackoverflow but none of them answered my problem, and I think having an example here will help you to help me.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like they're using fixed position with 100px right padding to just hide the scrollbar off the screen. Since you can't scroll on the x axis, you'll never see it even though it's there. Here's the relevant CSS.

```
.scrollWindow{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    padding-right: 100px;
}
```

[Here's the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9h765/1/)

Comment: Wow, that's actually really simple and smart. Can't believe I didn't figure it out. It works perfectly! Thanks alot.

Comment: I was really impressed with it too. I think I might use it on a site I'm working on now.